теплоход: приплыть или прибыть
В (немецком) учебнике были примеры «Теплоход приплыл в порт вовремя» и «Теплоход приплывёт по расписанию». Однако наша преподавательница сказала что это необычно: она всегда говорила бы «Теплоход прибыл в порт вовремя. Теплоход прибывает по расписанию.». Она использовала бы «приплыть/приплывать» только о других судах, например с словом «лодка». Как вы думаете?

https://politichanka.livejournal.com/169215.html

When I was about 10 years old, I took a ship-modelling class. We made scale copies of ships and learned maritime terms. On one occasion, our teacher taught us a phrase: корабли не плавают, а ходят. Плавает говно (shit). Since then, I have never used these words together - корабль (судно, теплоход, пароход) and плавать, only ходить - literally "to go". And such usage is typical for professional sailors. But ordinary people often say "теплоход плывет". Nevertheless I agree with your teacher. The phrases «теплоход приплыл в порт вовремя» и «теплоход приплывёт по расписанию» are acceptable, but sound sub-optimal, as if the vessel were a log carried by the current. In my view, it is better to say «теплоход прибыл в порт вовремя» и «теплоход прибудет по расписанию» - it sounds perfect! It is also possible to say «теплоход пришел в порт вовремя» и «теплоход придет по расписанию» but it's a bit like sailors' jargon or official terminology.

Поэтому и существует такая профессия, как капитан дальнего хождения.

Of course to say that the ship "приплыл" would be vulgar.  Arrived! The ship has arrived. But for a boat "приплыла" is quite appropriate.

Since теплоход is a type of ship, I'd use приплыл. Both are acceptable, прибыл is more broad.

Thank-you. Is your preference based on Russian as you hear it spoken around you, and if so, do you think your location makes a difference? If it does, where is that?

I don't think it makes a difference. It is based on what I've read online on forums or heard in movies or TV shows. I only studied abroad in 1 city - Kazan, and this wasn't a topic that I've encountered. IMO it is similar шаурма/шаверма both are acceptable. If you want to know more I suggest reading some classics or maybe ru.wikipedia articles. But to my ear, these uses are equivalent and your tutor is needlessly complicating things. I've had one teacher tell me I should pronounce often without the 't' like ofen. its just semantics. As long as people understand and you don't sound weird ur ok

I think "Прибыл" has a note of following some sort of itinerary or schedule. Same word can be used for trains arriving at a platform.

You don't use the verb "плавать" (float) with ships in Russian, unless they have lost their engine and are just floating with the current. For a small boat without an engine it's acceptable.

@Vosoni says who? orc nation idc about

https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/30753/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82?newreg=d077e0af8dad417b973b26523595f352
